# $F'$ and $E'$ are isomorphic isometrically.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $F$ be a dense subspace of the normed space $E$.
> Prove that $F'$ and $E'$ are isomorphic isometrically.

At first I was trying to define a function to check the isomorphism and then show that it preserves the norm. However, I couldn't think of a function that is an isometric isomorphism and preserves the norm at the same time. So, I found some sources and I saw that this function defined as
$$\varphi:F'\to E' \text{ as }\varphi(f\mid_F)=f.$$
But I don't understand why this function is well defined, is an isometric isomorphism and why it's defined like that. Can someone explain it to me? I don't get why the density property is important as well.

Note: $E'$ and $F'$ are the spaces of continuous linear functionals. The topological dual of $E$ and $F$, respectively.

Comment: Maybe simpler to start with $\psi:E'\to F'$ defined by $\psi(f)=f|_F$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So, who is $f$ to be honest? And why is that function an isomorphism? Is the density property used to show that $\varphi$ is well defined?

Comment: When someone says "define $\psi:E'\to F'$ by $\psi(f)=f|_F$" that should make it clear that $f$ is an element of $E'$. Why is it well-defined? It's obviously well-defined! That means the result is independent of any "choices" that were made, and here there are no such "choices". Why do you think it might not be well-defined? Why is it an isomorphism? That would be telling (this is where the density is used).

Comment: (The reason taking $f$ to go in the other direction seems simpler is precisely so we don't have to worryabout it being well-defined...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My concern to see if it's well defined is dealing with a function that can't actually be an application, but since we're not dealing with representatives of a class, in fact we can say it's "obvious", right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm sorry, but it's not clear why it's an isomorphism. Can you give me some tips? No need to justify, but I would like a north to understand.

Comment: Regarding why it's obviously well-defined: right. Why it's an isomorphism: It's trivially a homomophism. Density shows it's injective, and one of the three or four big theorems about Banach spaces shows it's surjective.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\psi \colon E' \to F'$ given by $\psi(f) = \left. f \right|_F.$ For surjectivity, let $f \in F'$ be given. Then we can extend $f$ to $\tilde{f} \in E'$ (since $f$ is continuous and densily defined). This extension coincides with $f$ on $F$ hence $\psi(\tilde{f}) = f,$ so $\psi$ is surjective.

Remains to show that $\psi$ is isometric (this will imply that $\psi$ is injective), i.e. $\left\|f\right\| = \left\|\left. f\right|_F\right\|.$ It is clear that $\left\|\left. f\right|_F\right\| \leq \left\|f\right\|.$ For the other inequality. Let $\epsilon>0$ and find $x\in E$ with  $\left\|f\right\| \leq |f(x)| + \epsilon,$ and you can find $y \in F$ such that $\left\|x-y\right\| < \epsilon$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$ (Note $f$ is continuous and $F$ is dense in $E$). Then we have
\begin{align*}
\left\|f\right\|& \leq |f(x)| + \epsilon \\
& \leq |f(x)| - |f(y)| + |f(y)| + \epsilon \\
& \leq \left|f(x)-f(y)\right| + |f(y)| + \varepsilon \\
& \leq |f(y)| + 2\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Taking $\epsilon \to 0,$ yields $\left\|f\right\| \leq \left\|\left.f\right|_F\right\|.$

In conclusion $\psi$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: Isometric implies injective, so you can shorten your answer a bit.

Comment: Indeed, good point!

Answer (score 2):

Since $F$ is a dense subspace of $E$, it is natural to define
$$\varphi: E' \to F': f \mapsto f\vert_F.$$
Clearly this map is linear. To see that it is isometric, you will have to invoke density of $F$ in $E$. To see the surjectivity, use the Hahn-Banach theorem.